# SQL Server restore replicated database

Tags: sql-server

I have setup a transactional replication on a sql 2008 database.
Then I backup the database.I got following error when I try to restore the database.
'Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use'

Do I have to remove the replication before restore database?

Comment: I'm only going to comment, because I haven't done it in a long time, but yes in general, you have to stop the replication when you do these things.  Try and fill out your question a little more, are you trying to restore the backup into the primary database or the replicated copy?

Comment: Try to restore primary database and really don't want to delete replication. but looks like there is no way to stop but delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a full backup, and there's no real-time application being in use in the database. I would suggest stopping and deleting the database for a complete clean up. After that the restore can be done and the replication could be setup automatically from the restore.

Answer (score 0):

It means a connection is open to the database while you're attempting to restore. You need to set the database to single-user mode first.

PS. If I remember correctly, you'll lose all the system procedures created by the replication process. You'll have to re-initialize the subscription.

Comment: not able to set primary database to single-user mode when there is replication using the database as publication. I want to restore the primary database without deleting the replication. not sure if it is possible.